# Integrating a function containing an integral

Tags: r

Assume the following is defined in the global environment:

```
theta = .9
sigma = .2
x0 = .7
mu = 12
```

I have the following function which contains the result of an integral:

```
f <- function(x){
  g <- function(t){
    2*mu*(theta - t)/(sigma^2)
  }
  return(exp(integrate(g, lower = x0, upper = x)$value))
}
```

When I try to integrate the function:

```
integrate(f, lower = -1, upper = 1)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in integrate(g, lower = x0, upper = x) : 
  'upper' must be of length one
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to vectorize your values for `upper`, e.g., using `sapply` like below

```
f <- function(x) {
  g <- function(t) {
    2 * mu * (theta - t) / (sigma^2)
  }
  sapply(x, function(v) exp(integrate(g, lower = x0, upper = v)$value))
}
```

or `Vectorize`

```
f <- function(x) {
  g <- function(t) {
    2 * mu * (theta - t) / (sigma^2)
  }
  Vectorize(function(v) exp(integrate(g, lower = x0, upper = v)$value))(x)
}
```

such that

```
> integrate(f, lower = -1, upper = 1)
16536 with absolute error < 0.016
```

Comment: Thanks so much @ThomasIsCoding ! How did you know? Why is not vectoring causing an error?

Comment: @DarbyBond You can add `browser()` before the line `sapply(...)` and will see the values of `x`, which is a vector, not a scalar.